# Enable HTTP/2 for Spring Boot on Jetty

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jetty

I have a Spring Boot 2.0.0 RC2 with embedded jetty and I want to enable HTTP/2.

According to [docs on how to enable http/2 for jetty](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.RC2/reference/html/howto-embedded-web-servers.html) I added `server.http2.enabled=true` to my `apllication.properties`

And my `pom.xml` looks like this:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RC2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude the Tomcat dependency -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Use Jetty instead -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-alpn-conscrypt-server -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-alpn-conscrypt-server</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.8.v20171121</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty.http2/http2-server -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.http2</groupId>
            <artifactId>http2-server</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.8.v20171121</version>
        </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Then I start it and do some GET requests (first one is HTTP1, second is HTTP2). Here is the output:

```
2018-02-26 18:24:59.670  INFO 20338 --- [           main] o.s.b.web.embedded.jetty.JettyWebServer  : Jetty started on port(s) 8080 (http/1.1) with context path '/'
2018-02-26 18:24:59.674  INFO 20338 --- [           main] ru.example.vpndemo.VpnDemoApplication    : Started VpnDemoApplication in 4.772 seconds (JVM running for 5.45)
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Feb/2018:15:25:11 +0000] "GET /example/ HTTP/1.1" 200 13 
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Feb/2018:15:33:52 +0000] "PRI * HTTP/2.0" 426 0
```

Why does my 2nd request prints as `PRI` in console?

Here is a cURL output for HTTP1 request:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/example/ -v
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /example/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Mon, 26 Feb 2018 15:37:03 GMT
< Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 13
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
Hello Spring!
```

And here is the output for HTTP2:

```
$ curl --http2-prior-knowledge http://localhost:8080/example/ -v
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x1ac3f90)
> GET /example/ HTTP/2
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
curl: (16) Error in the HTTP2 framing layer
```

Looks like HTTP2 is still not enabled. If so, how do I enable it for Jetty (I know, that it can be easily enabled for Tomcat or Undertow).

If it is already enabled, then what am I doing wrong to get the desired output?

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

**UPD**

To make sure my cURL is working properly with HTTP2 i started app with Undertow HTTP2. Here is the output:

```
$ curl --http2-prior-knowledge http://localhost:8080/example/ -v
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x2582f90)
> GET /example/ HTTP/2
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS updated)!
< HTTP/2 200 
< content-type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
< content-length: 13
< date: Mon, 26 Feb 2018 14:31:06 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
Hello Spring!
```

Comment: You started HTTP/2 without TLS/ALPN or any encryption?

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt As for Undertow/Tomcat, I think it's optional. Is it required? May I ask you to give a reference to this requirement?

Comment: I believe no encryption HTTP/2 is `h2c` (an upgrade for http/1.1 to http/2) - https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7540#section-3.1 - which is not the default behavior on jetty, and you have to configure for `h2c` separately.  Your linked documentation even says "Spring Boot does not support h2c, the cleartext version of the HTTP/2 protocol. So you must configure SSL first."

Comment: Have a look over here https://hoogvliet.de/http2-and-spring-boot

Comment: which version of java your are running on?

Comment: @nareshgoty when i first asked this question, it was Java 8. now it can also be 11

Answer (score 1):

The sequence ...

```
PRI * HTTP/2.0

SM
```

Looking like `"PRI * HTTP/2.0\r\n\r\nSM\r\n\r\n"` is the "HTTP/2 Connection Preface"

See: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-3.5

```
In HTTP/2, each endpoint is required to send a connection preface as
a final confirmation of the protocol in use and to establish the
initial settings for the HTTP/2 connection.  The client and server
each send a different connection preface.
```

Comment: I didn't know about that. Thanks. But why isn't there a request itself in logs, only it's preface. Is it not enabled TLS/ALPN that leads me to the error `curl: (16) Error in the HTTP2 framing layer` or what else can it be?

Answer (score 1):

For http/2 and jetty application server via maven dependency management:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-alpn-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-alpn-conscrypt-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.http2</groupId>
        <artifactId>http2-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```